# Two introductory linear algebra problems

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, multilinear-algebra

I remember when I was in Moscow one of my homework questions was:

> Is there a $2\times 4$ matrix whose $2\times 2$ minors are:
>
> a) $(2,3,4,5,6,7)$
>
> b) $(3,4,5,6,7,8)$
>
> c) $(5,6,7,8,9,10)$

This problem is supposed to be an easy application of some basic result in multilinear algebra, but I still do not know how to solve it. I also want to ask the question for $n\times m$ matrix and $n\times n$ minors in general, for which we will have $\displaystyle C^{m}_{n}=\frac{m!}{n!(m-n)!}$ numbers to choose. I only know this is somehow related to intersection varieties, but the problem is really *tiny*, so there should be some easy solution of it.

The second problem, which appeared in my last year's final, was this:

> Let $A$ and $B$ be two matrices with $m$ rows and $n\ge m$ columns. Prove that $$\det(AB^{t})=\sum_{I}\det A_{I} \det B_{I},$$ where the sum is running over all increasing sequences $I=(i_{1},i_{2},\dots,i_{m})\subset (1,2,\dots,n)$ and $A_{I},B_{I}$ mean $m\times m$-submatrices formed by $I$-columns.

This problem gives me the same feeling that it is supposed to be elementary and solvable by simple tools, but I could not unravel it via standard tools available. I feel there must be some better way to do it than expanding right side to equal the left side, etc. It has been one year and I still do not know how to solve it; so I decided to ask in here. This is from past exam so I think it is ok to ask online now.

Comment: I think you should edit out the second question and post it as another question on this site.

Comment: @Rasmus:I thought about it, but I do not think posting a lot of homework level problems everyday is a good thing.I certainly do not want to make mathstackexchange into my personal questionnaire. Thanks for commenting.

Comment: As you wish... The general rule is to post only one question at a time, in order to make life easy for answerers.

Comment: @Rasmus: Okay. I shall abide to the general rule. I will not divide this post into two separate posts, but I shall keep on that in future. Thanks for reminding me this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the second question, the formula is called the [Cauchy-Binet formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Binet_formula), and the wikipedia page has a proof.

---

A higher level perspective which indicates how one might actually derive the formula is the following.  Given a linear map $A:V\to V$, what is $\det(V)$?  If we wedge $A$ together with itself $\dim V$ many times, we get a linear map $\bigwedge^{\dim V} A: \bigwedge^{\dim V}V\to \bigwedge^{\dim V}V$.  However, since $\bigwedge^{\dim V}V$ is a one dimensional vector space, this map must be multiplication by a scalar.  This scalar is $\det(A)$.

Because $V\mapsto \bigwedge^k V$ is functorial, if we have two linear transformations $A,B:V\to V$, we have that $\bigwedge^{\dim V} (AB)=(\bigwedge^{\dim V} A)(\bigwedge^{\dim V} B)$, and hence $\det(AB)=\det A \det B$.

What if we have a linear maps $A:V\to W$ and $B:W\to V$, and we want to compute $\det(BA)$?    By functoriality, we have $\det(BA)=\bigwedge^{\dim V}(BA)=(\bigwedge^{\dim V} B)(\bigwedge^{\dim V} A)$.  Thus, we need to understand $\bigwedge^{\dim V} B$ and $\bigwedge^{\dim V} A$.

Let $\dim V = m$ and $\dim W=n$ with $m\leq n$, and fix a basis of $V$ and $W$ so that $A$ and $B$ are given as matrices.  Then we have a basis for $\bigwedge^{\dim V} W$ given by taking wedges of $m$ basis vectors of $W$, which is in correspondence with $m$ element subsets of $[n]=\{1,2,\ldots, n\}$.  If $S\subset [n]$, we let $w_S$ be the corresponding basis vector.  The coordinate of $\bigwedge^{\dim V} A$ corresponding to $w_S$ is exactly the minor coming from taking the columns from the set $S$.  Something entirely similar happens with $B$.

We are left with two transformations $\mathbb{F}\to \mathbb{F}^{\binom{n}{m}} \to \mathbb{F}$, and we have that the coordinates of the transformations correspond to minors.  Calculating the composition gives the formula.

---

For the first question, while Luboš Motl has already provided a good answer, there is some additional context to had.  The map that sends an $m \times n$ matrix to it's minors is a form of the [Plücker embedding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pl%C3%BCcker_embedding), which embeds Grassmannians inside of projective space (and in particular shows that the Grassmannian is a projective variety).

Your particular case, which parameterized lines in $P^3$,  is the prototypical example, and it is a classical result that the embedding is defined by a single quadratic relation (see [the wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pl%C3%BCcker_coordinates).  The problem you have is to determine which of those particular points are on the quadric defined by the embedding.

If I had to guess, I would say that this is why you were assigned the problem and what you were supposed to get out of it.

Comment: I know some of the material but do not know them well. Thank you! I felt I learned something new and fundamental.

Answer (score 4):

Privět, concerning the first problem, the minors don't change if the two 4-component rows of the $2 \times 4$ matrix are being subtracted from each other (like if you solve a set of linear equations) - because the 6 entries are really the components of a wedge products of the two 4-dimensional rows. In particular, without changing the minors, I can always bring the matrix to the form
$$\begin{array}{ccc} e&0&a&b\\0&1&c&d\end{array}$$
The minors are then $e,ec,ed,-a,+b,ad-bc$. Note that I only have five parameters $a,b,c,d,e$ now to adjust six minors in your list. How do you figure out whether the six numbers may be written in this form? Note that in my list, once again,
$$e,ec,ed,-a,+b,ad-bc$$
it's true that the last 6th entry multiplied the 1st one is equal to minus  (the 4th times 3rd plus 5th times 2nd), $e(ad-bc)$. This formula looks unnatural but it must be possible to order the six minors as $A,B,C,D,E,F$ so that
$$AB+CD+EF=0.$$
This is a nicely symmetric formula and there must exist a more covariant way to derive it, without putting zeros at some random places haha. Oh, I actually know how to derive the formula in a simple way. The 6 minors are the components of the wedge product $W = r_1\wedge r_2$ which belongs to a plane, so its wedge-square - a 4-form - has to vanish. Then it's enough to collect the coefficients in front of $e_1\wedge e_2\wedge e_3\wedge e_4$ of $W\wedge W$ - note that the latter doesn't vanish identically because they're two even 2-forms so the wedge product is symmetric. This coefficient will obviously look like $AB+CD+EF$.

At any rate, the equation above clearly can't be satisfied with positive minors. However, I am confident that with other positions of the zeros, and/or conventions for the signs of the minors, you may flip some signs in the equation above (two sign flips are equivalent to one - it's the only form of the equation inequivalent to the three identical terms), to get
$$AB+CD=EF$$
In this form, it's straightforward to test the permutations of your three lists of minors. The possible values of $AB+CD-EF$, using all possible permutations of the six minors $A,B,C,D,E,F$, in the three cases are:

> {-20, -19, -16, -11, -9, -5, -4, -1, 0, 4, 5, 7, 8, 11, 12, 13, 16, 17, 20, 23, 24, 25, 28, 29, 31, 32, 35, 36, 40, 43, 44, 45, 49, 52, 53, 56}
>   {-18, -17, -14, -7, -5, -1, 2, 5, 6, 10, 13, 14, 15, 19, 21, 22, 23, 25, 26, 30, 34, 35, 37, 38, 41, 43, 46, 47, 49, 50, 54, 58, 59, 61, 65, 70, 71, 74}
>   {-8, -7, -4, 7, 9, 13, 20, 23, 24, 28, 32, 35, 37, 41, 43, 47, 48, 49, 52, 56, 60, 61, 64, 65, 67, 71, 73, 77, 80, 83, 84, 88, 92, 97, 99, 103, 112, 113, 116}

Note that zero is only found in the first case, so only $(2,3,4,5,6,7)$ can be produced as minors of such a matrix. The Mathematica code I used:

```
a = {2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7} + p {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1};
f[v_] := v[[1]]*v[[2]] + v[[3]]*v[[4]] - v[[5]]*v[[6]];
b = Permutations[a];
Union[Map[f, b] /. {p -> 0}]
Union[Map[f, b] /. {p -> 1}]
Union[Map[f, b] /. {p -> 3}]
```

If I extend the function $f$ above to

```
f[v_] := {v, v[[1]]*v[[2]] + v[[3]]*v[[4]] - v[[5]]*v[[6]]};
```

then the results will also show me the right permutation that produced zero:
$$ 2\times 5 + 3\times 6 - 4\times 7 = 0.$$
Then it's straightforward to write down a matrix that has the right minors
$$\begin{array}{ccc} 2&0&1&-3/2\\0&2&3&5/2\end{array}$$
The subdeterminants are $4,6,5,-2,3,7$ for the pairs of columns $12,13,14,23,24,34$.

Comment: Thank you! I really hope I could do this myself...

Comment: Dear user, it was a pleasure. I also had to do some hard work before I could see the relevance the exterior "square" of the exterior product, or $AB+CD+EF$. I still haven't managed to write down a sensible story in which the minors are all positive. Maybe if it is minors multiplied by $(-1)^{i+j}$ where $i,j$ are the indices of the omitted columns, it can be made positive.

Answer (score 1):

The second question can be simply answered via differential forms. Concider linear maps $f(x)=B^t x$, $g(y)=Ay$, $z=f(y(x))$. Then the volume $m$-form $w=dz_1\wedge dz_m$ of  can be written out as the rhs in question. Lhs can be regarded as  volume dilatation coefficient of the resulting map $f\circ g$. Without differential forms this proof can be viewed sort of "volume of the image of a unit cube after $f\circ g:\mathbb R^m\to\mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R^m$ is equal to the sum corresponding to all oriented projections $P_L g$  of mappings $\mathbb R^m$ into $m$-dimentional coordinate subspaces $L\subset \mathbb R^n$: $f\circ g=\sum_L f\circ P_L g$."

Comment: This is really great. I never thought about this before. Thanks!